# Calling an attribute in a function into another function in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

Below is a code snippet

```
    function currmonth
    {
    curr_mon=`echo $(date +%x)`
    yy=`echo $curr_mon| awk '{print substr($0,9,2)}'`
    mm=`echo $curr_mon| awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'`
    dd=`echo $(date -d "$mm/1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%d")`   # <--
    }
    function test
    {
     echo $(currmonth.dd)                                  # <--
    }
```

I want to call the attribute "dd" which is in function "currmonth" to the function test
I tried using the .'DOT' operator to echo it but doesnt help,can u assist me with this

Comment: May I recommend the terminology 'using' instead of 'calling' (you call programs or functions), and 'variable' instead of 'attribute'. The `$(...)` notation is 'command substitution'; it runs the command inside the parentheses and the value is the standard output from that command. The name `currmonth.dd` might be a command name (but probably isn't); it is nothing to do with the function `currmonth`. You should be able to use just `echo $dd` unless `ksh` makes variables in functions non-global by default (which I'm tolerably certain it doesn't).  Shells use 'global variables by default'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` is a **variable**. You can print its value with:

```
function test
{
    echo $dd
}

currmonth    # call currmonth()
test         # call test()
```

Comment: but what if i have the variable'dd' in two or more functions, how will it differentiate

Comment: eg: function currmon{dd} function prevmon{dd} function test{echo $dd} here how can we call the specific variable from the function

Comment: Unless you declare a variable local to a function, it is global by default, so both functions are accessing the same `dd`.

Comment: @Rahulsawant: in addition to what @chepner said: if the variable is not local, then it can be accessed (and EDITED) globally. It's only the global variable dd. But if it's declared "local", then it's only visible from within that scope (ie, you can't access it from another function or another part of the script). If you have several function with each their "own" dd, you need to differentiate them and instead declare&use another global variable (ex: `curr_mon_dd`, etc, in your "currmonth" function), and access it from the other function using that differentiated name.